# Installing and using pod

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I'm having issues using a pod. I want to initialise Backendless and use as backend, but Xcode cannot resolve the library as it seems. When I try(AppDelegate.swift):

```
import UIKit


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {


let APP_ID = "xxx"
let SECRET_KEY = "xxx"
let VERSION_NUM = "v1"

var backendless = Backendless.sharedInstance()

var window: UIWindow?
```

I get

> Use of unresolved identifier 'Backendless'

and what I did was:

1. Create a new project, closed xCode.
2. Created a pod file and edited it to take my library
3. Installed without fault
4. Opened the workspace file generated with the pod instalment.
5. Built project

and then I tried to initialise the library as shown above.

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'Test' do
pod 'Backendless'
end

target 'TestTest' do

end
```

I have tried cleaning, building and restarting xcode. But I suspect I'm missing a crucial step somewhere?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Aren't you missing a `import Backendless` or something similar?

Comment: @Larme Where and how? Next to "import UIKit"? And what may the syntax be? I tried with import Backendless , but it doesn't recognise it.

Comment: @Benni When I use `use_frameworks!` I almost always import the module using `import module` then just build the project. This usually fixes any import issues I have

Comment: If you use Swift, add to your bridging header file the following... see full description https://github.com/Backendless/ios-SDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since you are specifing:

```
use_frameworks!
```

in your podfile, in order to use any on your pods, you must use ***import*** in order to use the specific pod in the file you want to use it.

In your AppDelegate.swift:

```
import UIKit
import Backendless
```

Second of all, your pod name should be

```
pod 'Backendless-ios-SDK'
```

https://github.com/Backendless/ios-SDK

Comment: No such Module 'Backendless' is the error when trying to import.

Comment: Is the pod name you are installing correct? Check this out 

pod 'Backendless-ios-SDK' (https://github.com/Backendless/ios-SDK)

Comment: I reinstalled with the correct pod name. Still the same. Saw a ticket on Backendless describing to use "#import <Backendless-ios-SDK/Backendless-Bridging-Header.h>" in the bridging header. But where is that?

Comment: You must create a Bridging Header file in order to import objective-c code into a Swift project. Since this is not the original question, heres a like: http://www.learnswiftonline.com/getting-started/adding-swift-bridging-header/